# How to setup buildbot for

Tags: python, git, dependencies, buildbot

I am quite new to buildbot and struggling to create a configuration for the following python code structure:

A library containing some general classes and functions and two programs who depend on the one library. All three have their own git repository. Lets call the library `the_lib` and the programs `prog_a` and `prog_b`.

What I would like `buildbot` to do for me is periodically check the repositories for changes and if so rebuild what is necessary. So a change to the source of `the_lib` should rebuild all three, a change to the source of `prog_a` should only rebuild `prog_a` and a change to the source of `prog_b` should only rebuild `prog_b`.

I am at the point where I am able to build any of the three when its source changes but how do I introduce de dependency of `prog_a` and `prog_b` on `the_lib`?

Cheers,
Feoh

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger multiple builders with a single source change, in the following example the first two each trigger their own builds, but the third one triggers all three:

```
  yield basic.AnyBranchScheduler(
            name = prog_a, treeStableTimer=delay,
            change_filter = my_a_filter,
            builderNames = [prog_a],
            )

  yield basic.AnyBranchScheduler(
            name = prog_b, treeStableTimer=delay,
            change_filter = my_b_filter,
            builderNames = [prog_b],
            )

  yield basic.AnyBranchScheduler(
            name = the_lib, treeStableTimer=delay,
            change_filter = my_lib_filter,
            builderNames = [prog_a, prog_b, the_lib],
            )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the usage of yield? If you have an interesting example of dynamically generating a config, can you share the interesting bits? Thanks!

Comment: I use yield here on the assumption that you need to return these items into c['schedulers'] in your master.cfg file  My master.cfg file has this line: c['schedulers'] = schedulers = list(config.schedulers.get_schedulers()) The code above is in the config/schedulers.py which is imported into master.cfg

Answer (score 0):

For the changes in the `prog_(a|b)` you can use a simple [single branch scheduler](http://buildbot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#singlebranchscheduler) that will call their builders.

For `the_lib` you have two options:

1. Create a [Dependant](http://buildbot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#dependent-scheduler) scheduler for the builders of `prog_a` and `prog_b`, and set the upstream scheduler as the single branch scheduler of `the_lib`.
2. Configure for the `prog_(a|b)` a [Triggerable](http://buildbot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#triggerable-scheduler) scheduler, and trigger them using the [Trigger](http://buildbot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#triggering-schedulers) build step from `the_lib` builder.